# Mysql Select two columns in a virtual one

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this query

```
SELECT post_id, set_type, field_id, votes
FROM birr_multi_values
WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT post_id 
    FROM birr_multi_values
    GROUP BY post_id 
    HAVING 0<>SUM(votes)
)
ORDER BY post_id, set_type, field_id DESC
```

that it's showing this result:

[image: query result]

What I want to obtain is something like this

[image]

I would like to create a virtual column with the values from the "field_id" and "votes".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `GROUP BY post_id, set_type` and use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT post_id, set_type, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('field_id:',field_id, ', votes:', votes)
    ORDER BY field_id DESC
    SEPARATOR '; '
  ) new_virtual_column 
FROM birr_multi_values
WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT post_id 
    FROM birr_multi_values
    GROUP BY post_id 
    HAVING 0<>SUM(votes)
)
GROUP BY post_id, set_type
ORDER BY post_id, set_type
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36oKGFPNLSQxvFYCqHRKvn/1).